# SELECT with comparison operator, based on an order, skipping row(s)

Tags: mariadb, sorting

I have a resultset from a **SELECT** query, based on a certain **ORDER BY** condition, and I’m trying to check the integrity of the order in which the resultset is rendered. First, I’m specifying a **LIMIT**, on the basis of which, the resultset size is limited. Then, I’m selecting a random **PK** value from the resultset, get a particular row and use the comparison operator on that row value(s), for the next **SELECT**. Something like this(Let’s suppose **a** is the random row from above):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl where tbl_columnX > a.fieldX and tbl_columnY > a.fieldY
ORDER BY certain fields
```

Basically, what I’m trying to do here, is to ensure that for a resultset (**R**) of certain order, when choosing a random **PK** value, and issuing a **SELECT** statement with comparison operator(s) on that **PK** based row value(s), the resulting set(**S**) contains the rows that are in **R**, after/before the **PK**, depending whether the order is ascending or descending.

It is basically working, except for a few cases where the next row(s) after the **PK** based row, have the same value(s) as the **PK** based row, in a few column(s). For example, these are the last few rows, from the resultset **R**:

```
ID(varchar)     VALUE(varchar)  DESC1(text)     DESC2(text)     NAME(text)
-------------   -------------   -------------   -------------   -------------
62E212AF            C09A        F/T/K              AH            AN
CAFFA217            C09AA       F/T/K 2            Ah            An
D90222CC            C09BA       F/T/K 2d           Ahod          Anod
```

Now, if I try to get a new resultset(**S**) after the `ID 62E212AF`, it skips the `ID CAFFA217`, and the first ID in the resultset is `D90222CC`. The similar pattern is repeated in a few other places. This is how I’m doing the order by, in this particular case:

```
order by 
  NAME asc,
  VALUE asc,      
  DESC1 asc, 
  DESC2 asc, 
  ID asc
```

I’d really appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 0):

All sorting are alphanumeric, and follow the ascii code 
that means

```
1 decimal representation 49
N decimal representation 78 
n decimal representation 110
```

*1* comes before *N* and that before *n* and so on, so far as i can tell it is sorting correctly.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557172/mysql-order-by-sorting-alphanumeric-correctly) shows how you can sort the text "correctly"